# Верстка прогрессбара

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, вёрстка

Добрый вечер!

Помогите, пожалуйста, с версткой. Я программист, а не верстальщик, поэтому решил попросить помощи у сообщества. Нужно сверстать вот такой блок:

[image: Блок с прогресс баром]

Заказчик согласился поменять прогресс бар, который на картинке - на прогресс бар [jQuery UI animated](http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/#animated), только с условием, что я вместо оранжевого сделаю зеленый цвет.

Вот что у меня получилось на данный момент:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>jQuery UI Example Page</title>
        <link type="text/css" href="css/trontastic/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){

                // Progressbar
                $("#progressbar").progressbar({
                    value: 0
                });

                // Анимация ProgressBar'a, расчитанная на сутки!
                $(function() {
                    var pGress = setInterval(function() {
                    var pVal = $('#progressbar').progressbar('option', 'value');
                    var pCnt = !isNaN(pVal) ? (pVal + 1) : 1;
                    if (pCnt > 100) {
                    clearInterval(pGress);
                    } else {
                    $('#progressbar').progressbar({value: pCnt});
                    }
                    },(24*6*6*1));

                // Вывод процентов, вида 99.99%, на поле прогресс бара!
                var myPer = 0;
                $("#progressbar")
                    .progressbar({ value: myPer })
                    .children('.ui-progressbar-value')
                    .html(myPer.toPrecision(3) + '%')
                    .css("display", "block");
});

            });
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .ui-progressbar .ui-progressbar-value { background-image: url(images/pbar-ani.gif); }
            /*demo page css*/
            body{ font: 62.5% "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif; margin: 50px;}
            .demoHeaders { margin-top: 2em; }
            #dialog_link {padding: .4em 1em .4em 20px;text-decoration: none;position: relative;}
            #dialog_link span.ui-icon {margin: 0 5px 0 0;position: absolute;left: .2em;top: 50%;margin-top: -8px;}
            ul#icons {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
            ul#icons li {margin: 2px; position: relative; padding: 4px 0; cursor: pointer; float: left;  list-style: none;}
            ul#icons span.ui-icon {float: left; margin: 0 4px;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- Progressbar -->
        <h2 class="ui-progressbar ui-progressbar-value">Progressbar</h2>
        <div id="progressbar">
            <!--<div>59%</div>-->
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Еще очень далеко от оригинала, к сожалению... В общем очень расчитываю на Вашу помощь!

То, что есть сейчас:

[image: jQuery UI Progress Bar]

Comment: Плюс под прогресс баром мне нужно сделать блок обратного отсчета, как на картинке. Начальная точка отсчета 24 ч. 00 мин. 00 сек., подскажите как реализовать на JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте [конструктор тем UI](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/). Или создать кастомную тему, или выбрать [готовые из галереии](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/#ffDefault=Lucida+Grande%2C+Lucida+Sans%2C+Arial%2C+sans-serif&fwDefault=normal&fsDefault=1.1em&cornerRadius=10px&bgColorHeader=3a8104&bgTextureHeader=03_highlight_soft.png&bgImgOpacityHeader=33&borderColorHeader=3f7506&fcHeader=ffffff&iconColorHeader=ffffff&bgColorContent=285c00&bgTextureContent=05_inset_soft.png&bgImgOpacityContent=10&borderColorContent=72b42d&fcContent=ffffff&iconColorContent=72b42d&bgColorDefault=4ca20b&bgTextureDefault=03_highlight_soft.png&bgImgOpacityDefault=60&borderColorDefault=45930b&fcDefault=ffffff&iconColorDefault=ffffff&bgColorHover=4eb305&bgTextureHover=03_highlight_soft.png&bgImgOpacityHover=50&borderColorHover=8bd83b&fcHover=ffffff&iconColorHover=ffffff&bgColorActive=285c00&bgTextureActive=04_highlight_hard.png&bgImgOpacityActive=30&borderColorActive=72b42d&fcActive=ffffff&iconColorActive=ffffff&bgColorHighlight=fbf5d0&bgTextureHighlight=02_glass.png&bgImgOpacityHighlight=55&borderColorHighlight=f9dd34&fcHighlight=363636&iconColorHighlight=4eb305&bgColorError=ffdc2e&bgTextureError=08_diagonals_thick.png&bgImgOpacityError=95&borderColorError=fad000&fcError=2b2b2b&iconColorError=cd0a0a&bgColorOverlay=444444&bgTextureOverlay=08_diagonals_thick.png&bgImgOpacityOverlay=15&opacityOverlay=30&bgColorShadow=aaaaaa&bgTextureShadow=07_diagonals_small.png&bgImgOpacityShadow=0&opacityShadow=30&thicknessShadow=0px&offsetTopShadow=4px&offsetLeftShadow=4px&cornerRadiusShadow=4px)

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ, но это не совсем то...